# Why does HashSet.Contains followed by HashSet.Add allow duplicates?

Tags: c#, .net-core, data-structures

**UPDATE**

It doesn't. As indicated in some of the answers, it was a logic error in the code being tested.

```
// corrected logic:
string storedName;
// this runs as many times as needed to find a valid entry (not already present)
while (StaticSet.Contains(storedName = GetRandomName()))
{
}
StaticSet.Add(storedName);
```

---

Original question:

A friend wrote a solution for a coding exercise on Exercism's C# track that called `HashSet<string>.Contains` to see if a value exists in a hashset. It the check returned false, they then added the value using `HashSet<string>.Add`.

The exercise included unit tests to validate correctness, and their solution failed the unit tests.

The code passed when the `Contains` check was skipped and `Add` was used directly.

I don't know why this happened. Does `Contains` use the object hashcode and `Add` uses equality, so they check different things? Is there some race condition in the code?

Demonstration of the behavior:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace HashSetTest
{
    class Program
    {
        public static HashSet<string> StaticSet = new HashSet<string>();
        private const string LetterPool = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        private const string NumberPool = "0123456789";
        private static readonly Random Random = new Random();
        static string GetRandomString(int length, string chars) => new string(Enumerable
            .Repeat(chars, length)
            .Select(s => s[Random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());

        static string GetRandomName() => GetRandomString(2, LetterPool) + GetRandomString(3, NumberPool);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Collision when using contains then add: {ContainsCheckCollides()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Collision when using add: {AddResultCollides()}");
        }

        public static bool AddResultCollides()
        {
            var localSet = new HashSet<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10_000; i++)
            {
                string storedName;
                while (!StaticSet.Add(storedName = GetRandomName()))
                {
                }
                if (!localSet.Add(storedName))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        public static bool ContainsCheckCollides()
        {
            var localSet = new HashSet<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10_000; i++)
            {
                string storedName;
                // bad logic alert: runs 0 or 1 times only, 
                // and never tries to add duplicates to the StaticSet
                while (!StaticSet.Contains(storedName = GetRandomName()))
                {
                    StaticSet.Add(storedName);
                    break;
                }
                if (!localSet.Add(storedName))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Those are not quite equivalent, the first inner `while` will run multiple times, the second inner `while` will run at most once because of the `break` in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Contains` and `Add` work perfectly fine, your loops have different logic. To implement logic of the `Add` one using `Contains` + `Add` you should do something like this:

```
while (StaticSet.Contains(storedName = GetRandomName()))
{
}
StaticSet.Add(storedName);
```

Your current code for `Contains` + `Add` case will run the `while` loop at most once - and when it will run it zero times you will get your collision, i.e. if `StaticSet` does not contain current generated `storedName` - it will be added to it and the execution of `for` loop continues (cause `localSet` definitely does not contain `storedName`), but if `StaticSet` contains `storedName` - the body of `while` loop is not executed (`!StaticSet.Contains(...) == false` => `while(false)`) the execution is continued to `localSet.Add` which definitely contains the value, so you get your `true` result.

Answer (score 2):

> The code passed when the Contains check was skipped and Add was used directly.
>
> I don't know why this happened. Does Contains use the object hashcode and Add uses equality, so they check different things? Is there some race condition in the code?

The difference between the two with respect to the unit tests is simply because the two methods have different semantics. I.e. ignoring the relationship between `Contains()` and `Add()`, they still don't actually have the same behavior.

As far as the difference between `Contains()` and `Add()` goes…

`Contains()` and `Add()` use the same logic to determine whether an item is already in the set. They don't *"check different things"*.

Unless there is some concurrency (multithreading) in the code that wasn't shown in the question, there is no race condition. You need two or more threads to have a race. There would be a race if you did have two threads both trying to call either of those methods concurrently; note that since the `HashSet<T>` class is not itself thread-safe, it's really only a matter of degree.

The race looks worse with the `Contains()`/`Add()` version of the code, but there's still a race when only calling `Add()` because internally the data structure is not thread-safe and there are still operations that occur that would race with each other if `Add()` were to be called concurrently from two or more threads.

As for why the `HashSet<T>` class was designed this way, ultimately the answer is simply that that's what the designer of the class decided would be the most useful. Similar to why `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` allows overwriting the value of an existing key with a new value when using the indexer, even those that class's `Add()` method does not allow a duplicate key. Ultimately, it comes down to what the use scenarios are and what will lead to the simplest, most correct code for users of the class.

Note that the `Add()` method returns a `bool` value indicating whether the item was in fact added to the set. So the `Add()` method provides the same functionality as `Contains()`, plus the behavior of actually adding an item to the set when it's not already there. All the code needs to do is observe the returned value, and it will tell the caller whether the item was newly added to the set (i.e. returns `true`), or was already present (returns `false`).